# Does Observable.race for two observables work more than one time?

Tags: rxjs, store, effects, ngrx

Tasks is: I have two effects (ngrx/store), let's say ef1$ and ef2$, which are Observables. In angular component I would like to detect which one is triggered. I added the following code:

```
 Observable.race(ef1$, ef2$)
     .subscribe((payload) => {
          if (payload.type == ThreadActions.THREAD_READY_TO_BE_RENDERED) {
            // do one thing
          }
          else if (payload.type == ThreadActions.THREAD_ITEM_READY_TO_BE_RENDERED) {
            // do another thing
          }
        });
```

But it looks like that after first emit of any effects Observable.race is going to be dead and no reaction more on additional emits, despite of I sure that effect executes again and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what is you desired functionality but if you want to use the `race` operator multiple times you'll need to complete the chain when it emits a resubscribe immediately:

```
Observable.defer(() => Observable.race(ef1$, ef2$))
  .take(1)
  .repeat()
  .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @martin . That's what I was looking for. But I'm worried about overhead of resubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.race()` will only emit whichever the emission comes first.

If you want two Observable streams and observe them concurrently aka you do not care whoever will be emitting, use `Observable.combineLatest`:

```
Observable.combineLatest(ef1$, ef2$)
    .subscribe(([ef1,ef2]) => {

        //ef1.type will be ThreadActions.THREAD_READY_TO_BE_RENDERED
        //ef2.type will be ThreadActions.THREAD_ITEM_READY_TO_BE_RENDERED

        //check if ef1 is truthy
        if(ef1){
            //do one thing
        }
        if(ef2){
            //do another thing
        }
    });
```